# Mockito.when().thenReturn() not used by other methods

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I have the following test setup:

```
class RepositoryTest {
    private lateinit var repository: Repository

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        repository = Mockito.mock(Repository::class.java)
        Mockito.`when`(repository.getList()).thenReturn(getMockedList())
    }

    // works
    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun getList() {
         val list = repository.getList()
         assertNotNull(list)
         assertFalse(list.isEmpty())
    }

    // does not work
    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun getList() {
        // getFilteredList is internally using getList()
        val list = repository.getFilteredList()
        assertNotNull(list)
        assertFalse(list.isEmpty())
    }
}
```

So my question is, does the mocking of the return type for getList not work for implicit method calls? And what would be the appropriate way to mock these implicit method calls?
getFilteredList

Comment: Mockito.`when`(repository.getList()).thenReturn(mockedList) from where you are feeding mockedList ? not find declaration for the mock

Comment: @lib4 it wasn't meant to be a running piece of code. Rather, a definition of my setup... Just image a function providing a filled list instead. I will update the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how mocks work.

Your `repository` is a mock object and does not contain any actual code. By default, for all methods that return a value, a mock will return either null, a primitive/primitive wrapper value, or an empty collection. Since `getFilteredList()` is not stubbed, you're getting a default return value that does not pass the assertions you have later.

You can make the mock call your actual method with something like

```
when(repository.getFilteredList()).thenCallRealMethod()
```